# Unknown type name 'namespace'

Tags: xcode, facebook, react-native

I currently work on a react-native 0.29.1 app. I updated to 0.29.1 and cannot build anymore. The error i get is the following:

```
Unknown type name 'namespace'
```

It looks like an error in the assert.h from Facebook. When i right click on the erroneous file and open it in the Finder i get the following path:

```
MyApp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/fb/include/fb/assert.h
```

But the include tree on the left says something different.

[image: Screenshot 1]

This are my header search paths

[image: Screenshot 2]

EDIT: I think i found my error but i don't know why this happed. I cleaned up the header paths and removed everything except the 3 default paths and it works now. Can someone tell me why xcode created this paths instead of them i provided?

The problem was line 4.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Please, post your error in text instead of images

Answer (score 0):

Try to update xcode to the latest version or use for compilation objective-c++ instead objective-c.